# 3D rotation in 2 directions?

Tags: java, opengl, rotation, lwjgl, angle

**Background**

I'm trying to create a FPS game in Java using LWJGL 3.0. I've set up a camera class, that has a pitch and yaw (roll is not being used). The camera itself extends Entity, as it has a model. This model I would like to appear to always be "in front" of the camera, wherever the camera is pointing. Each Entity has a method `getTransformationMatrix()` which returns a `Matrix4f`, that is then passed into the entity shader.

**Problem**

The model needs to point in the direction of the camera, as well as rotate around the camera, such that it is always in front. The object in this situation is hands with a gun, as shown in the photo below.

[image]

**My Attempt**

I am aware of basic trigonometry, so I got the object to rotate correctly for pitch and yaw, separately. This is my current implementation:

*Yaw*

```
@Override
public Matrix4f getTransformationMatrix() {
    modelX = getPosition().x + (radius * (float)Math.sin(Math.toRadians(getYaw())));
    modelZ = getPosition().z + (radius * (float)Math.cos(Math.toRadians(getYaw())));

    return Transform.createTransformationMatrix(new Vector3f(modelX, getPosition().y - 5, modelZ), new Vector3f(0, getYaw(), 0), getScale());
}
```

*Pitch*

```
@Override
public Matrix4f getTransformationMatrix() {
    modelZ = getPosition().z + (radius * (float)Math.sin(Math.toRadians(getPitch())));
    modelY = (getPosition().y - 5) + (radius * (float)Math.cos(Math.toRadians(getPitch())));

    return Transform.createTransformationMatrix(new Vector3f(getPosition().x, modelY, modelZ), new Vector3f(getPitch(), 0, 0), getScale());
}
```

I have done some research but I fear I have been stuck on this too long and need some fresh eyes. When I try to combine these 2 calculations, the model seems to move in the shape of a graph when looking at any yaw angle other than 0. Below is my attempt of combining these:

```
@Override
public Matrix4f getTransformationMatrix() {
    float zAxis = (radius * (float)Math.sin(Math.toRadians(getPitch())));
    modelY = (getPosition().y - 5) + (radius * (float)Math.cos(Math.toRadians(getPitch())));
    modelZ = getPosition().z + (zAxis * (float)Math.cos(Math.toRadians(getYaw())));
    modelX = getPosition().x + (radius * (float)Math.sin(Math.toRadians(getYaw())));

    return Transform.createTransformationMatrix(new Vector3f(modelX, modelY, modelZ), new Vector3f(getPitch(), getYaw(), 0), getScale());
}
```

The `Transform.createTransformationMatrix()` looks like the following:

```
public static Matrix4f createTransformationMatrix(Vector3f translation, Vector3f rotation, Vector3f scale) {
    transform3d = new Matrix4f();
    transform3d.setIdentity();
    Matrix4f.translate(translation, transform3d, transform3d);
    Matrix4f.rotate((float) Math.toRadians(rotation.x), new Vector3f(1, 0, 0), transform3d, transform3d);
    Matrix4f.rotate((float) Math.toRadians(rotation.y), new Vector3f(0, 1, 0), transform3d, transform3d);
    Matrix4f.rotate((float) Math.toRadians(rotation.z), new Vector3f(0, 0, 1), transform3d, transform3d);
    Matrix4f.scale(scale, transform3d, transform3d);
    return transform3d;
}
```

**Thoughts**

A friend suggested creating a unit vector that points in the direction of up, (ie. `new Vector3f(0, 1, 0)`) rotating the Vector by the pitch and yaw, then multiplying the Vector by the radius and adding it to the camera's position. I tried this, but I don't know how to rotate a Vector by an angle, and there seems to be no `Vector3f.rotate()` method in the slick-utils Vector3f class. Any help is is thoroughly appreciated as this has been giving me a headache for the past few days. Thanks!

Comment: Rotating for any angle around any axis is a matrix 4x4 as described [here](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glRotate.xml). Rotating for *yaw* and then for *pitch* is a matrix multiplication of two matrices. Be aware of the order, it isn't the same as *pitch* and then *yaw*.

Comment: Do you really need this matrix (i.e. placement in the world)? Wouldn't it be enough to have the matrix in view space, where it is constant? When you draw the model, set the view matrix to identity (since your model is already in view space) and set the model matrix appropriately (probably just a slight translation away from the camera).

Comment: @NicoSchertler I have a view matrix that is passed into the shader, and the transformation matrix which is also passed in, then they are multiplied in the shader to calculate world space for each vertex of the model. How would what you are suggesting apply to this? I tried applying just the view matrix in the shader but it didn't work properly

Comment: I was saying not to apply the view matrix (set to identity). Then, the model will have a constant location with respect to the camera.

Comment: I will check when I'm home and let you know, thanks!

Comment: @NicoSchertler I tried this, I had a boolean in the `getViewMatrix()` method, and in the EntityRenderer it checks if the entity is the camera, if so it loads up a view matrix which is just an Identity matrix. What should I be loading into the transformation matrix? Just the offset relative to the camera? I could not see the model after applying the changes described above

Comment: Yes, it is usually just an offset (maybe a rotation too, depending on the model). If you don't see the model, it is probably behind the camera (or at least in front of the znear plane).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What we normally do is, yes, take a unit-length vector and use it as our "axis". In 2D rotation we use an axis - the Z axis - all the time.

[3D rotation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hoCS6.png)

If you were to look at the axis, like in 2D, you would see something like this

[2D rotation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KaACA.png)

So, to rotate a point in 3D you can use a matrix or a vector. I recommend the vector first so you can get an idea of how 3D rotation works. It blows your mind!

I'll drop the code from a Vector3f class from theBennyBox . If you're interested in more of this math check out theBennyBox on Youtube.

Vector3f

```
    public Vector3F rotate(float angle, Vector3F axis) {
    double a = Math.toRadians(angle / 2f);
    float hs = (float) Math.sin(a);
    float hc = (float) Math.cos(a);
    Vector4F r = new Vector4F(axis.getX() * hs, axis.getY() * hs, axis.getZ() * hs, hc);
    Vector4F rc = r.conjugate();
    r = r.multiplyAsQuat(this).multiplyAsQuat(rc);

    return new Vector3F(r.getX(), r.getY(), r.getZ());
    }
```

Vector 4f

```
    public Vector4F multiplyAsQuat(Vector3F v) {
    float o = -x * v.getX() - y * v.getY() - z * v.getZ();
    float a = w * v.getX() + y * v.getZ() - z * v.getY();
    float b = w * v.getY() + z * v.getX() - x * v.getZ();
    float c = w * v.getZ() + x * v.getY() - y * v.getX();

    return new Vector4F(a, b, c, o);
}

    public Vector4F conjugate() {
    return new Vector4F(-x, -y, -z, w);
}

    public Vector4F multiplyAsQuat(Vector4F qt) {

    float o = w * qt.getW() - x * qt.getX() - y * qt.getY() - z * qt.getZ();
    float a = x * qt.getW() + w * qt.getX() + y * qt.getZ() - z * qt.getY();
    float b = y * qt.getW() + w * qt.getY() + z * qt.getX() - x * qt.getZ();
    float c = z * qt.getW() + w * qt.getZ() + x * qt.getY() - y * qt.getX();

    return new Vector4F(a, b, c, o);
}
```